What is Paul trying to say in 1 Corinthians 1:23-24
1 Corinthians 1:23-24 (ESV):

23 but we preach Christ crucified, a stumbling block to Jews and folly
to Gentiles, 24 but to those who are called, both Jews and Greeks,
Christ the power of God and the wisdom of God.

It seems Paul says that Christ being crucified is a stumbling block/folly to nonbelievers, but to believers Christ is the power of God and the wisdom of God.
How do those 2 ideas relate and what is the meaning of this?

Answer
Paul teaches a consistent doctrine that God always works in a mysterious way and contrary to the values and expectations of the secular world.
Explanation
The secular world has the concept of a savior, a hero who always comes on a horseback with a sword, a club or even a machine gun, kills his opponents and saves his lover, or his family, or relatives or at the maximum, a small/large group of people.
This is the theme of most of the fictions or movies the world produces.
Here is the picture of a real Savior of God depicted in the Scripture: a defenseless Person, forsaken by all including His own closest disciples, sentenced to the most humiliating punishment on earth, an Object of contempt from the so called self-righteous gentlemen of the world, naked, spat upon and dying helplessly on a cross. An utter failure! A real “foolishness”!
How can the secular world reconcile this picture of weakness with their concept of a hero? Yet, through this one act, God set the stage for the entire world so “that the world might be saved through Him” (John 3:17)!
But how did God convert this “foolishness/weakness” into a very powerful case for Him?
Paul gives the answer:

“But if Christ has not been raised, your faith is foolish”
(1 Cor 15:18).

Yes, God converted this foolishness into the most powerful thing by raising Christ from the dead and exalting Him to the highest title (Php 2:9).
If there was no resurrection of Jesus, then the world would have been right and wise and God would have been wrong and foolish.

“But now Christ has been raised from the dead; He became the
firstfruit of those having fallen asleep” (1 Cor 1:21).

Thus, now,

“Christ is the power of God and the wisdom of God; because the foolish
thing of God is wiser than men, and the weak thing of God is stronger
than men” (verses 24-25).

The Jews & the Rock of Stumbling
This was already prophesied in the OT (Isaiah 8:14-15and Luke 2:34). The problem with the Jews was that they were self-righteous (Rom 10:3).
How did they establish their own righteousness?
Jesus gives the answer:

“You are good at rejecting God's commands (the Ten Commandments) so
that you can follow your own teachings!” (Mark 7:9).

They were so pre-occupied with the “works of Law” which involved the “foods and drinks, and various washings, and fleshly ordinances (animal sacrifices), until the time of setting things right has been imposed” (Heb 9:10).
They never could accept a mere Carpenter of Nazareth as the Lamb of God that takes away the sins of the world and Whose precious blood reconciles the world to God.
They could never understand that “it is impossible for the blood of bulls and goats to take away sins” (Heb 10:4).

“For the (works of) Law had a shadow of the coming good things,
not the image itself of those things. Appearing year by year with the
same sacrifices, which they offer continually, they never are
able to perfect the ones drawing near” (Heb 10:1).

The Jews couldn’t grasp this truth because God “locked them up all in unbelief” so that He will show mercy to all later (Rom 11:32).
So, “until today, when Moses (OT) is read, a veil lies on their heart” (2 Cor 3:15) which but will be removed and “ALL Israel will be saved” (Rom 11:26).
God’s Wisdom
When all Israel was locked up in unbelief, God fulfilled 2 things in one go:

The self-righteous Jews will understand that they are a special people to God not because of any of their virtue but solely because of God’s grace and election (Rom 9:11).

The Gentiles (the wise secular world) will understand that they are also special to God because God does not show any partiality (Col 3:25) to His images and likenesses! But they will have to let go of their self-taught wisdom.


Conclusion
The two ideas (salvation of Gentiles and Jews) are related in this:

“God did what he had purposed, and made known to us the secret
plan he had already decided to complete by means of Christ. This
plan, which God will complete when the time is right, is to
bring all creation together, everything in heaven and on earth,
with Christ as head. All things are done according to God's plan and
decision” (Eph 1:9-11; GNB).


If we paraphrase the second clause as "The Jews treat it as'a stumbling-block' and the Gentiles call it 'folly'", that would probably help our understanding of the verse.
The Jews "stumble over" the teaching of "Christ crucified" because they regard the event as a sign of weakness, which appears to be inconsistent with their understanding of God. That is why Paul counters their view by saying "No, this event really is a sign of God's power, despite appearances"
When Paul refers to "the Greeks" here, he is thinking of the philosophers rather than the idolaters. They are rather proud of their wisdom, and regard the "Christ crucified" teaching as "folly" because they cannot begin to understand how it might work in accomplishing what God intends. It is counter-intuitive. That is why Paul counters their view by saying "No, this event really is a sign of wisdom, specifically God's true Wisdom, despite appearances".
